# How to read json files in subfolders?

Tags: python

I have a file path like this `'/mnt/extract'`. Now inside this `extract` folder, I have below 3 more subfolders -

```
subfolder1
subfolder2
subfolder3 (it has one .json file inside it)
```

The json in `subfolder3` looks like this -

```
{
    "x": "/mnt/extract/p",
    "y": "/mnt/extract/r",
}
```

I want to extract the above json file from `subfolder3` and concatenate the value - `/mnt/extract/p` for the key `'x'` with one more string `'data'` so that the final path will become `'/mnt/extract/p/data'` where I want to finally export some data. I tried the below approach but it's not working.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in list(os.walk(path)):
    for name in files:
        print (os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: @martineau that was a typo. I have edited it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You still haven't explained why you're using the `'x'` key from the JSON file in `subfolder3` (and not, say, the `'y'` key).

Comment: this is the requirement that i have to fetch the value of key x and not y

Comment: OK. Do you know the name of the file in `subfolder3` in advance?

Comment: no, business will place this file regularly and hence we should not be aware of this name beforehand

Comment: Do you know the names of `subfolder1`, `subfolder2`, and `subfolder3` in advance? If not, how do you know to read the JSON file in `subfolder3` (to get the `'x'` value from)?

Comment: If you don't know them in advance, is there some other way to identify the folder?

Comment: I have solved it finally :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the in-built python Glob module, you can read files in folders and sub-folders.

Try this:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('./mnt/extract/**/*.json', recursive=True)
```

The files list will contain paths to all json files in the extract directory.

Try this:

```
import glob

final_paths = []
extract_path= './mnt/extract'
files = glob.glob(extract_path+ '/**/*.json', recursive=True)

for file in files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        json_file = json.load(f)
        output_path = json_file['x']+'/'+'data'
        final_paths.append(output_path)
```

The `final_path` variable will contain the output of all json files in the folder structure.

Comment: i am getting output as [] which means empty list

Comment: My bad, I had a type which is fixed now. There was a missing "." before the folder name. It should be files = "glob.glob('./mnt/extract/**/*.json', recursive=True)". Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: files is returning a list and because of this when i try to parse json using with open(files, 'r') as f, i am getting this error - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: Iterate over the list using a for loop. For example: for path in files: // Do stuff

Comment: @SumitDwivedi "dict" is a keyword, you should not use it as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
extract_path= '/mnt/extract'
files = glob.glob(extract_path+ '/**/*.json', recursive=True)
if len(files) != 0:
  with open(files[0], 'r') as f:
    dict = json.load(f)
final_output_path = dict['x']+'/'+'data'
```

In the above code, files object is returning a list containing JSON file as the only element. To make sure that we pass json object to the open method and not list, i took files[0] which will pick the json file element from list and then it was parsed easily.If anyone has some other suggestion to handle this list object which is retuning from glob function, feel free to answer as in how can we handle it in a more cleaner way.